# Multiple line input string using fgets

Tags: c, string, fgets

I want to input a multiple-line string using:

```
fgets(str,100,stdin)
```

and then output the same string.
For example:

Input:

```
my name is sandy
i am learning C
```

and the output should be:

```
my name is sandy
i am learning C
```

Comment: That's great.  Do you have a question?  `fgets` is certainly a suitable function to use to get started.

Comment: You read multiple lines in fgets itself is impossible. If strcat later...

Comment: Have you looked at "loops" in your book yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *mfgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream){
    int ch, i=0;
    if(n<1)return NULL;
    if(n==1){
        *s = '\0';
        return s;
    }
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(stream))){
        s[i++] = ch;
        if(i == n - 1) break;
        if(ch == '\n'){
            char next = fgetc(stream);
            if(next == '\n')
                break;
            else
                ungetc(next, stream);
        }
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i == 0 ? NULL : s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char str[100];
    printf("input (only newline is end)\n");
    mfgets(str, 100, stdin);
    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```